# How to remove the access rights to a linked google account after the deletion of an account at firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication, google-one-tap

I just implemented the possibility to delete the personal account at Firebase of an Android application. I then discovered that the application is still listed on the Google account with having access rights even though the Firebase account is already deleted.

Comment: I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have implemented the option to sign in your users to Firebase with Google, then most likely you already have followed these steps:

- [Authenticate with Google on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)
- [Get started with One Tap sign-in and sign-up](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started)

According to:

> I just implemented the possibility to delete the personal account at Firebase of an Android application.

If you have **only** deleted the Firebase authentication account it doesn't mean that everything related to Google is wiped out, because it's not.

To achieve what you want, I recommend you follow the below steps in the **exact order** I have added:

1. Sign-out the user from Google using [SignInClient#signOut()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/identity/SignInClient#signOut()) method.

> Signs out the currently signed-in user if any.

2. Delete the Firebase user account using [FirebaseUser#delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#delete()) method:

> Deletes the user record from your Firebase project's database. If the operation is successful, the user will be signed out.

3. Delete all data in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) using [DocumentReference#delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#delete()), or the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) using [DatabaseReference#removeValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#removeValue()),  if it exists.

So in the case of 2. there is no need to explicitly sign out the user from Firebase because when you delete the account, the user will be signed out automatically.

P.S. Please also remember that all three operations are **asynchronous**. So you need to wait until the operations are complete. In java, you can use a [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) object and in Kotlin you can use [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html).

**Edit:**

Regarding [FirebaseUser#unlink(String provider)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#unlink(java.lang.String)) method, it only:

> Detaches credentials from a given provider type from this user.

I have even written an article regarding this topic:

- [How to authenticate to Firebase using Google One Tap in Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I just don't understand where the GoogleSignInClient should be created. In the linked tutorial only the OneTapClient(SignInClient) is used. Also, I found the FirebaseUser.unlink() method and wanted to ask what it does. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You're very welcome. It should be created in the activity where you want to revoke the user. So please see my updated answer. Is clear now?

Comment: Hey Alex. It worked! Thank you so much for your help! I'm just a bit confused because I used two different client objects for the deletion process, the SignInClient(for reauthentication) and the GoogleSignInClient(for revoking access). I remember implementing Google sign-in to Firebase a year ago. But I only used the GoogleSignInClient without One Tap. From what I've read, One Tap is the newer way to log in. Now I'm just wondering if the use of GoogleSignInClient is somehow outdated, or if it's correct to use both clients in one project. P.S. Sorry for the late answer

Comment: You're very welcome, Yannick. Good to hear that it worked :) The mechanism for [implementing sign-in with Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) will be deprecated, and not the class itself. So you can continue to use an instance of that class to sign out your users.

Comment: Okay great! :D Then I thank you again and wish you a nice day!

Comment: A nice day to you too ;)